# Does reader/read-string attach metadata to the forms

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I've read somewhere that `cljs.reader/read-string` attaches metadata to the forms that it creates, like the position in the string read.
Is it true? Is it documented somewhere?
Thanks.

Comment: For the record I'm gonna try with InstaParse. See [the docs about positions as metadata](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse#line-and-column-information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read-string` doesn't add metadata to the returned form:

```
=> (meta (cljs.reader/read-string "(prn 0)"))
nil
```

Your compiled functions/defs/vars will have this type of metadata though:

```
=> (meta #'my-fn)
{:ns app.core,
 :name my-fn,
 :file "src/cljs/app/core.cljs",
 :end-column 20,
 :column 1,
 :line 125,
 :end-line 125,
 :arglists ([{:keys [x]}]),
 :doc nil,
 :test nil}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `cljs.reader`, but if you use `clojure.tools.reader`, you can do this. It's not particularly well documented, but you can see how by looking at the tests: https://github.com/clojure/tools.reader/blob/master/src/test/cljs/cljs/tools/metadata_test.cljs#L62-L70

In short, you have to pass the string to `clojure.tools.reader.reader-types/indexing-push-back-reader`, and from there to `clojure.tools.reader/read`. (In the test/example above, they first pass to `reader-types/string-push-back-reader`, but this doesn't appear to be strictly necessary).